# How to solve PHP date() NULL value 1969?

Tags: php, mysql, date

cI use jQuery calendar date picker on my form. When the date is not filled, it always shows "1969-12-31" value. I did not want to show this value, 0000-00-00 is fine for me.

My MySQL date column is `receive_dt DATE NOT NULL,`

This is a snippet code from the PHP file to handle the form.

```
...

$rcv_dt = $_POST['receive_dt'];
    list($year,$month,$day)=explode('/',$rcv_dt);
    $timestamp=mktime(0,0,0,$year,$month,$day);
    $receive_dt=date('Y-m-d',$timestamp);

..., receive_dt) VALUES (....,'$receive_dt')...
```

I've tried to do the strtotime() but no luck.

```
$receive_dt=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($rcv_dt));
```

I've even changed the MySQL `reveive_dt column to DATE NULL`, but still no luck.

Comment: http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png

Comment: @imulsion for a moment I thought it was a "nsfw" pic lol

Comment: @PiLHA well, not quite, but why would I post that anyway?

Comment: Yeah, I am aware of that.... this is still in ealy development, I am going to sanitize all inputs later after solving this.

Comment: This is an interesting issue...

Comment: @hangee: Don't treat security as a feature that you strap on at the end. Write secure code from the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the fact that you're getting the end of 1969 rather than the beginning of 1970 (the "Unix epoch" begins at midnight on 1st Jan 1970) suggests you have some timezone-handling bug causing you to "lose" an hour, so just a heads-up on that.

Now, the reason you're seeing this at all, is that PHP's date formatting functions treat whatever input you give them as a number; if you give them an empty string, or `null`, this will be converted to the number `0`, and interpreted as the beginning of the Unix epoch - 1st Jan 1970. MySQL will probably do something similar if you try to pass it an empty string or `0` when populating the column.

What you need to do is specifically detect this case - easy enough if your application should never actually have 1st Jan 1970 as input - and specifically insert a `NULL` into the database rather than formatting the date.

Comment: not a time zone handling bug but just being east from UTC will produce valid dates before 1970, as the Unix Epoch is based off UTC.

Comment: @MartinSamson Ah, I hadn't thought of it like that. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$invalid_dates='1969-12-31'; // anything before

$rcv_dt = $_POST['receive_dt'];

if(strtotime($invalid_dates) >= strtotime($rcv_dt))
{
$rcv_dt='0000-00-00'; // or $rcv_dt=date('Y-m-d'); // today
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php

Answer (score 1):

Learn to use the `DateTime` object. Using `strtotime`, `mktime`, and other integer based time formats is an outdated and bad approach.

```
$dt = date_create($_POST['receive_dt'] ?: '');
if ($dt !== false)
{
  echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // insert this value
}
```

Comment: This answer is not valid anymore as it causes `Passing null to parameter #1 ($datetime) of type string is deprecated` notice

Comment: A deprecation doesn't mean it doesn't work; just that it may not in the future. That said, I updated the code to fix a mistake since the function returns false, not null on error. I did add a check to convert null values to empty strings. That said, my response was not intended as a drop-in solution to his problem. Point being - parse input strings using the date object, not integers.

Comment: I was merely pointing that "it is not valid anymore", not meaning to insult or question your knowledge. It would be nice to leave the previous answer in place in case someone still has to use php versions below 8.x and add your better solution under `update 2023`, Thank you for adding the new solution btw.

Answer (score 0):

if you send $receive_dt as an empty string `..., receive_dt) VALUES (....,'')...` (after checking the post variable is empty) then mysql will treat is as a null, otherwise php is sending a date of 0 which for mysql is the start date of the unix epoch.